# Conversion from String to Json Object not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, string

I get a response from an ajax call which looks like that:

`"[{"share_count":470,"like_count":145,"comment_count":173}]."`

That is exactly, how the Chrome debugger shows it.
Now I want to convert this string to a JSON object:

`var fbData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`

"data" is the Ajax response

however the variable "fbData" is a string if I check it afterwards:

`console.log(typeof fbData);` // results in string

Hopefully somebody can help me out!
I tried a lot of different things but the conversion won't work..

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Why you call `JSON.stringify(data)` on a string ? just need `JSON.parse` . Also you have a dot `.` at the end of your JSON that is not valid

Comment: There shouldn't be a period(.) at the end of your input string.

Comment: Depending on how your ajax query is executed, jQuery may have already parsed the data. See [ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) `dataType`

Comment: *"Conversion from String to Json Object..."* You're not converting it to a "JSON object." You're converting it to a JavaScript object. JSON is a *textual* notation; once it's parsed, you don't have JSON anymore, you just have native objects.

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you parse it:

```
var fbData = JSON.parse(data);
```

`JSON.stringify` is for taking objects and turning them into JSON strings. `JSON.parse` is for taking JSON strings and turning them into objects.

I'm assuming your string is really `[{"share_count":470,"like_count":145,"comment_count":173}]` (no `.` at the end).

Note that if you've retrieved this data via jQuery, then as [Jon notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849776/conversion-from-string-to-json-object-not-working#comment51620070_31849776), jQuery may well have **already** parsed it before giving it to you. Since you didn't quote your code, we can't help you more with that, but it may well be that you can use `data` directly.

Comment: ok so here is the code snipped
    posting.done(function(data){
  var fbData = JSON.parse(data); //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
  console.log(typeof data); // results in "string"
  var table = document.getElementById("url_table");
  for (var j = 1, col; col = table.rows[rowCount].cells[j]; j++) {
   col.innerHTML=data.share_count;
  } 
  
 });

Comment: @user3410232: To improve the question, use the "edit" link on the question, not comments. And be sure to show us what `posting` is.

Answer (score 0):

To parse the string as single JSON object use:

```
JSON.parse('[{"share_count":470,"like_count":145,"comment_count":173}]')
```

To parse the string as multiple JSON objects use:

```
JSON.parse('[{"share_count":470},{"like_count":145},{"comment_count":173}]')
```